# How to use setTimeout in constructor

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor:

```
function Domino() {

var self = this;
this.myElement = $("#smth");

this.rotation = 0;
this.rotateFor = function (deg, scl) {
    this.rotation += deg;
    this.scale = scl;
    this.myElement.find(".domino-view").css({
        transform: "rotate(" + self.rotation + "deg)  scale(" + self.scale + ")"
    });
};
```

I want to set timeout on `rotateFor`. I tried this:

```
this.rotateFor = function (deg, scl) {
    this.rotation += deg;
    this.scale = scl;
    this.myElement.find(".domino-view").css({
        transform: "rotate(" + self.rotation + "deg)  scale(" + self.scale + ")"
    });
}
this.start = function(){
self.timeout = setTimeout(function(){this.rotateFor()}, 5000)
```

}

Then I call it like this: `something.start()`, but it still does not work. How can I set timeout in this constructor?

Comment: @JamesThorpe that's not the problem here, since the OP has correctly passed `this` in the callback.  However he probably _hasn't_ passed the correct `this` when calling `self.timeout` in the first place.

Comment: @Alnitak That's what this dupe covers - the `this` contained within the callback passed to `setTimeout`?  OP already has `self`, just needs to use it as per the dupe.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the this.rotateFor call in a function. You can just write self.timeout = setTimeout(this.rotateFor, 5000); Although, bear in mind you are just setting what happens when you call timeout() here. You actually need to ensure that timeout() is called to make your rotateFor function fire.

Comment: @Alnitak: He has *not* correctly passed `this` in the callback. It uses `this` instead of `self`, and is not bound.

Comment: @ManoDestra I think the OP wants to be able to control when the `setTimeout()` begins, hence having it wrapped in a function.

Comment: Doesn't need it though, even in that instance. He's wrapping the rotateFor in an unnecessary anonymous function, which then just calls rotateFor. It's redundant.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the anonymous function, I was talking about the `start` function.

Comment: @Bergi you're right - I'm jetlagged :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `self` is not something which exists anywhere (within that scope). Secondly, `this` within the setTimeout function does not refer to the current object. You also need to call `rotateFor` within the correct context.

Use something like:

```
this.start = function(deg,scl){
    var self = this; //Must specify what self is.
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){ //This outside (self also works since we defined it)
          self.rotateFor(deg,scl); 
    }, 5000);
}
```

If you want to start the timeout within the constructor you can do the following:

```
function Domino() {

var self = this;
this.myElement = $("#smth");

this.rotation = 0;
this.rotateFor = function (deg, scl) {
    this.rotation += deg;
    this.scale = scl;
    this.myElement.find(".domino-view").css({
        transform: "rotate(" + self.rotation + "deg)  scale(" + self.scale + ")"
    });
};
setTimeout(function(){ 
    self.rotateFor(<p1>,<p2>); //Parameters needed
}, 5000);
```

Comment: `self` comes from `var self = this;`, it's fine.

Comment: `self` is declared in the first code block, rather than the smaller copy that contains just the rotate function and the attempt to call it.

Comment: Minor update. Need could pass the rotateFor parameters in the this.start function, otherwise I have no idea where you'll be getting them from. For the second case, no idea where you'll be getting them from in general.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `self` to create an instance variable and `this` in `setTimeout` where it won't refer to the right object instance.

```
function Domino() {

   var self = this;
   this.myElement = $("#smth");

   this.rotation = 0;
   this.rotateFor = function (deg, scl) {
       this.rotation += deg;
       this.scale = scl;
       this.myElement.find(".domino-view").css({
           transform: "rotate(" + self.rotation + "deg)  scale(" + self.scale + ")";
       });
   };

   this.start = function(){
      this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
          // Here is where the self variable benefits you:
          self.rotateFor();
      }, 5000);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind this:

```
setTimeout(function(){this.rotateFor()}.bind(this), 5000);
```